# Understanding the Definition of Hoeffding Bound

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, concentration-of-measure

As defined in the text of [CMU statistics notes](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat700/Lecture6.pdf). The Hoeffding's inequality is defined as:
$$P(|\bar{X}-\mu|\geq t)\leq 2 \exp\left(\frac{2n^2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n{(b_i -a_i)^2}}\right)$$
where $\mu=E[X_i]$.

I understand that in machine learning terms, as in PAC analysis, $\bar{X}-\mu$ means the difference between the observed mean and the true mean of the random variable $X$. However, what confuses me is the choice of the represnetation of $E[X_i]$, an expectation of a member $X_i\in X$ instead of $E[\bar{X}]$.

Is $E[X_i]$ a conventional expression for $E[\bar{X}]$? If yes, in what sense it is correct to put it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing $\mu=E(X_i)$ we mean that all the random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ has the same mean $\mu$ and hence $\overline{X}$ also has mean $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.